# C++ force type resolution for overloaded methods

Tags: c++, types, polymorphism, default-parameters, type-resolution

I have inherited code that looks similar to the following:

```cpp
struct A {
  typedef void * X;
};

struct B {
  typedef void * Y;
};

struct foo {
  void bar (A::X x, int a, int b) {
    return;
  }

  void bar (B::Y y, int c = 0) {
    return;
  }

  void baz (int i) {
    return;
  }

  void baz (float f) {
    return;
  }
};

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
  B::Y my_y;
  foo f;
  f.bar(my_y, 3);

  return 0;
}
```

I would really like to add default values to `void bar (A::X x, int a, int b)`, but the compiler begins to complain.

```
$ g++ main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:30:8: error: call of overloaded ‘bar(void*&, int)’ is ambiguous
   30 |   f.bar(my_y, 3);
      |   ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:10:8: note: candidate: ‘void foo::bar(A::X, int, int)’
   10 |   void bar (A::X x, int a = 0, int b = 0) {
      |        ^~~
main.cpp:14:8: note: candidate: ‘void foo::bar(B::Y, int)’
   14 |   void bar (B::Y y, int c = 0) {
      |        ^~~
```

Is there a way to sufficiently differentiate the types `A::X` and `B::Y` to make this possible?

Comment: A typedef doesn't create a new type, just another name. So all versions of `void*` are the same. To get an "overloadable" type, you need a *new* type, like `struct X` and `struct Y`.

Comment: `A::X` is the same type `B::Y` - live - https://godbolt.org/z/aa5dxM6cd  .  Boost has a library for strong typedefs which will create a new unique type, you might want to look at that.

Comment: Thank you @RichardCritten. Unfortunately, I am working on an embedded platform and I'm unable to use Boost. What mechanism is it using? Perhaps I could leverage that instead.

Comment: Oddly enough, compiling with msvc only complains that `my_y` is uninitialized. Setting `B::Y my_y = NULL;` compiles without warning or error and runs.

Comment: @dmedine You have to default the arguments `a` and `b` first, then it'll fail to compile.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what the OP was saying. What about simply changing `A::X` to `A` in the `bar` signatures?

Comment: As most of Boost is a header-only library you should be able to use it on any platform.  However you can see the code for strong typedef here (about 15 line macro) https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/boost/serialization/strong_typedef.hpp  _"...macro used to implement a strong typedef.  strong typedef guarentees that two types are distinguised even though the share the same underlying implementation...."_

Comment: The API is public facing, so while changing the signature is possible, it is not desirable. The boost method would still require a recompile, but is a close approximation for the end user and is the best candidate for a solution so far.